# Show that the set $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is a group under ordinary multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

To be a group, a set with a binary operation has to satisfy all four of the group axioms.
My problem is with closure as each time I am unsure if my proof suffices.
The set of positive rational numbers is defined as:
$\mathbb{Q}^+=\{\frac{a}{b}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$

To show that this set is closed under ordinary multiplication:

Let $$q_1=\frac{a}{b}\ \textrm{and}\ q_2=\frac{c}{d}\quad\forall a,b,c,d\in
   \mathbb{Z}^+$$

We see then that $$q_1q_2=\frac{ac}{bd}\in \mathbb{Q}^+$$

Does this suffice? I feel bothered that I have not shown $\frac{ac}{bd}$ is in the set of positive rationals. There must be a theorem I've forgotten or am not using.

Comment: First of all, you have defined the rationals, not the positive rationals. Second of all, you multiplied  $\Bbb{Q}_1$ and $\Bbb{Q}_2$ wrong. Third of all, don't use blackboard bold for variables as it can get confused with sets. Although your proof would be correct given this definition.

Comment: A few typesetting issues, it is strongly discouraged to use \mathbb for *variable names* (it should be reserved for special purpose names such as the rational numbers or integers).  Use $q_1,q_2$ instead.  Use \in to denote element inclusion, not \epsilon, and finally a rational number cannot have a denominator of zero.  Be careful of that.

Comment: @jgon I was careless to have missed out notating the Q and Z with a "+" subscript. I apologise for the carelessness with the multiplication. It's hard to keep a clear head when switching between workings and typing.

Comment: @user I see, that makes a lot of sense, in that case add in the pluses and your proof will be fine.

Comment: Depends what your instructor is looking for.  If I was marking the question I would probably be happy with the answer "it is well known that the product of two positive rationals is a positive rational": this shows that you know what "closed" means, which presumably is the reason for asking the question.  On the other hand, and please take this as a constructive criticism, I would take marks off for your awful notation.  For example, $\Bbb Q$ is not an individual rational number, it is the **set** of rational numbers.

Comment: @David I enjoy criticism. Quite a straight-talker myself. 
It helps that you point that out because I often find myself lost and confused with my own notation.

Comment: @jgon edit has been restricted so I'll leave it to anyone to do the editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of closure of multiplication of positive rational numbers:

Let $q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{Q}^+$.  Then $q_1 = \frac{a}{b}$ and $q_2=\frac{c}{d}$ where $(a,b,c,d)\in(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\})^4$.

You have then that $q_1\cdot q_2 = \frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d}$ which by definition of multiplication of rational numbers becomes $\frac{a\cdot b}{c\cdot d}$.  Note now that since the natural numbers are closed under multiplication and a product of natural numbers is zero if and only if at least one of the multiplicands is zero you have $(ac)$ and $(bd)\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.  Therefore, by definition, $q_1\cdot q_2\in\mathbb{Q}^+$.

---

You hadn't mentioned needing help with the other axioms, just closure.  For the others remember you need to prove existence of identity and existence of inverses as well as the associative property.

Comment: I don't need help with the other axioms. At least not now. 
Thank you.